# Timeout function works for one form but ignores the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I'm having a very specific problem. I have two forms on a page, bootstrap validator included and it works just fine, except that it doesn't have the RegEx check for email input. So I created a short RegEx validation, but when I try to handle error messages, they work as intended only for the second form. When I click submit button, error messages show up on both form, but timeout functions works nly for the latter one. Submit button for the top form keep creating new error messages whenever I click on it. Any advice? Please see my code below:

HTML:

Top form:

```
      <form action="" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Full Name:" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email Address:" required>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number:" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="amount" placeholder="Investment Amount (£)">
         </div>

        <button class="btn btn-block btn-submit" type="submit" name="submit">Enquire Now</button>
```

Bottom form:

```
    <form action="" method="POST" class="row form-find-more">
      <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name*:" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address*:" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3">
        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number*:">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3">
        <button class="btn" type="submit" name="submit">Submit Request</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

My jQuery snippet:

```
    <script>

    var emailReg = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|
    (".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-
    Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    var elm = $('<div class="help-block with-errors">Please enter a valid e-
    mail</div>');

    $(document).on('click', 'form button[type=submit]', function(e) {
    var isValid = emailReg.test(jQuery.trim($(e.target).parents('form').find("input[type=email]").val()));
if(!isValid) {
  e.preventDefault(); //prevent the default action
  $('form').append(elm);
}
 });


 setTimeout(function() {
 elm.detach();
 }, 5000);


 </script>
```

Comment: Try changing `$('form').append(elm);` to `$('form').append(elm.prop('outerHTML'));`  and in your timeout try doing `$('.help-block.with-errors').remove();`  I'm thinking the element is being attached to the first form, then being unattached and re-attached to the second form.

Comment: You have to differentiate both the form or both the input field to check validation by giving different name or id. because of having the same name it can not identify the exact field

Comment: Thanks Taplar, it works for both forms the same now, but only the first time I click submit. After that it keeps creating new divs and they don't dissapear (on both forms). How can I prevent that?

Comment: Much appeciated, both of you. I made some progress by nesting timeout function inside onclick function. Every click still creates multiple divs, but after 5 seconds they are all removed.

Comment: Changed the time interval to 3000, so even if you spam the submit button, they will keep disapearing after 3 seconds, or instantly, since every click triggers new timeout which removes them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix the problem by some code edits:

```
  var emailReg = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|
  (".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-
  9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  var elm = $('<div class="help-block with-errors">Please enter a valid e-mail</div>');

$(document).on('click', 'form button[type=submit]', function(e) {
var isValid = emailReg.test(jQuery.trim($(e.target).parents('form').find("input[type=email]").val()));
if(!isValid) {
  e.preventDefault(); //prevent the default action
  $('form').append(elm.prop('outerHTML'));
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.help-block.with-errors').remove();
  }, 3000);
 }
});
```

Thank you everyone who helped.